# Qt: onChildrenChanged not launched when QML components are created at runtime from C++ code

Tags: c++, qt, object, qml

For a project, I need to create QML components at runtime from C++.

My general architecture is the following:

Project1:

- Engine.h
- Engine.cpp
- CustObject.h
- CustObject.cpp
- Plugin.h
- Plugin.cpp
- Dummy.qml

Project2:

- main.cpp
- main.qml

What I want to do is instantiate Engine.cpp as a QML object (possible since I registered it in the Plugin class and made it available to Project2) and then create dynamically CustObject instances (which are also registered to be used by Project2) from Engine. In the end I want that if I write:

```
ApplicationWindow{
id: window
visible: true
    Engine{
        id: eng1
        CustObject{
            id: custObj1
        }
    }
}
```

This will be the same as writing something like

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true

    Button {
        text: "add new child"
        onClicked: {
            console.log("QML: Number children before", eng1.children.length);
            eng1.addNewChildren();
            console.log("QML: Number children after", eng1.children.length);
        }
    }
    Engine{
        id: eng1
        onChildrenChanged: console.log("Changed")
    }
}
```

And I should see that the number of children is incremented and onChildrenChanged from eng1 should be launched.

The problem is that neither the number of children is incremented, nor the signal onChildrenChanged is launched.

I had also the other problem that in order to add a children to the parent, eng1 in my case, I used the function QQmlComponent(QQmlEngine *engine, const QUrl &url, QObject *parent = 0) of QQMLComponent class. But I cannot find a way to transform my CustObject class into a QUrl since it is not a .qml file.

Therefore I first tried to add a dummy qml object called: Dummy.qml instead of CustObject object. Dummy.qml looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    property int nb: 1
}
```

The code of my Engine class looks like this:

Engine.h:

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QQmlComponent>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>


class Engine : public QQuickItem{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Engine(QQuickItem* parent = 0);

    virtual ~Engine();

    Q_INVOKABLE QObject* addNewChildren();

};

#endif // ENGINE_H
```

Engine.cpp:

```
#include "Engine.h"


Engine::Engine(QQuickItem* parent) :
    QQuickItem(parent)
{
}

Engine::~Engine(){ }


QObject* Engine::addNewChildren(){

    qDebug() << "CPP: Number children before " << this->children().size();

    QObject* parentEntity = this;
    QQmlComponent* childrenEntity;
    QQmlComponent component(qmlEngine(this), QUrl("qrc:///src/Dummy.qml"));
    QQuickItem *childrenItem = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(component.create());
    QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(childrenItem, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
    childrenItem->setParent(parentEntity);
    childrenItem->setProperty("nb", 2);

    qDebug() << "CPP: Number children after" << this->children().size();

    //qDebug() << "Property value:" << QQmlProperty::read(childrenItem, "nb").toInt();

    return childrenItem;
}
```

But my output when I run main.qml is the following:

```
    qml: QML: Number children before 0
    CPP: Number children before  0
    CPP: Number children after 1
    qml: QML: Number children after 0
```

And I commented the line corresponding to QQmlProperty::read due to the following error: "incomplete type 'QQmlProperty' used in nested name specifier
     qDebug() << "Property value:" << QQmlProperty::read(childrenItem, "nb").toInt();"
                                      ^

I have therefore the following questions:

1. Why is the number of children incrementation not seen from qml (but visible from cpp)?
2. Why is onChildrenChanged not launched from qml?
3. How can I add dynamically CustObject class (which is visible as a qml object from Project2 point of view since it is registered)
   instead of Dummy.qml?
4. How to read a property of a dynamically added object in C++ just after its creation (i.e. how to use QQMlProperty::read)?

Thank you a lot in advance for any help you could give me!

Comment: This is a private signal, you aren't supposed to be using it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Then what signal should I use to do an action when a child is added to my engine? And do you have any ideas why my children variable is not updated from qt view point but from c++ one yes?

Comment: Qt's internals are designed rather static and inflexible, you don't really have the option to change or tap into it. You could override it, but then who knows what you may break, all in all, it is not pretty. A better strategy is to alter your design to work around Qt's limitations. Have your own custom function for creating objects and emitting your custom signal to notify of that.

Comment: Thank you, but so you are telling me onChildrenChanged should not be used directly in any qml code? What about children variable? Isn't it a reliable variable that can be used to know the children count of a parent at any point? (in my case it is not reliable since it does not change from the qml perspective) Anyway I will investigate a new design. I had the idea of keeping a List<QObject *> of children for the Engine class and have an associated signal linked to this list. Do you think it is a good idea? Do you have any ideas for my 3 others questions? (1,3 and 4)

Answer (score 6):

> Why is the number of children incrementation not seen from qml (but visible from cpp)?

QML doesn't use `QObject::children()`, instead it uses [`QQuickItem::childItems()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#childItems). Yes, that's right, there are two different list of children, one from `QObject`, and one from `QQuickItem`. Both serve different purposes: The one from QObject is mainly for memory management (children get deleted when parent gets deleted), while the one from QQuickItem is for the 'visual hierachy', e.g. children get drawn on top of their parent. More details are available in [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-visualparent.html).

> Why is onChildrenChanged not launched from qml?

Because the `onChildrenChanged` is only emitted when `QQuickItem::childItems()` changes, which it doesn't. Call `setParentItem()` in addition to `setParent()` to fix that.

> How can I add dynamically CustObject class (which is visible as a qml object from Project2 point of view since it is registered) instead of Dummy.qml?

By simply creating the object yourself and setting the `parent` and `parentItem`. There is no need to use `QQmlComponent` here.

```
QObject childrenItem = new CustObject();
childrenItem->setParent(parentEntity);
childrenItem->setParentItem(parentEntity);
```

> How to read a property of a dynamically added object in C++ just after its creation (i.e. how to use QQMlProperty::read)?

Calling `QQuickItem::childItems()` should do the trick, no need to read a property. FWIW, there probably was an `#include <QQmlProperty>` missing in the code that didn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works :) I have now another problem: I want to create dynamically my CustObject but I want to use the beginCreate(QQmlContext *publicContext) of QQmlComponent. Indeed I want all my properties to be set before the onChildrenChanged is launched. Is there any way to use that function and at the same time using a custom component? Because for now on I only saw the use of that function by using loadUrl and qml object.

Comment: I can't have a look at that at the moment, I suggest you ask a new question so that others can see it, you'll probably get some answers that way.